# How to convert MySql code in laravel code?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Im building blog application in laravel and for that im using 3 tables: users posts and ratings. The user logs in and he can, among other things, rate posts. So i added column avgRating in posts table to store average rating of each post.

I tried to execute this code in mysql without laravel.

```
UPDATE posts p
    SET p.avgRating=
        (SELECT ROUND(AVG(r.rating), 0)
        FROM ratings r
        WHERE p.id=r.rateable_id)
```

and it works. I tried to write it like this in **PostController.php**

```
public function avgRating ($avgRating) {
    $posts = DB::raw('UPDATE posts p
    SET p.avgRating=
        (SELECT ROUND(AVG(r.rating), 0)
        FROM ratings r
        WHERE p.id=r.rateable_id)')->get();

  }
```

and it doesnt do a thing. Anyone can explain how to do this in laravel?

Comment: toSql(); method ?

Comment: You're just creating an expression, not running a statement. You can replace `DB::raw()` with `DB::statement()`

Comment: oke @aynber i will try DB::statement()

Comment: Don't forgot running COMMIT assuming a disabled autocommit on MySQL server level or session level..

Comment: @RaymondNijland i dont understand what you mean? Im new to laravel and this function i wrote here worked in app i worked only with pure php, no framework. and i just had to call it in one of my view files and it stored the data in database, now in laravel i dont know what to do

Comment: Normally MySQL works with a [autocommit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html) mode  ... If you or laravel change that with a query like `SET autocommit = OFF` then MySQL does not write changes to the table without [COMMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html)..  I assuming here that InnoDB is used as storage engine by the way..

Comment: @RaymondNijland autocommit is on

Comment: i worked with laravel ages ago but if that is the case what you are telling then it seams the query ever executes ... Check the [manual](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database) i believe you need to use `DB::statement('<query>');` or `DB::update('<query>')` then instead of `DB::raw(..)` ...

Comment: @RaymondNijland i did change it to statement and still nothing changes in database..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not doing a select to expect a returned result of the list of posts.

Second, `DB::raw()` only allow you to write raw SQL, it doesn't runs it. for that you can use `select()`, `update()`, `statement()`,...

For your example, you can

```php
DB::statement('UPDATE posts p
    JOIN (
        SELECT r.rateable_id, ROUND(AVG(r.rating), 0) as rounded
        FROM ratings r
        GROUP BY r.rateable_id
    ) a on p.id = a.rateable_id
    SET p.avgRating=a.rounded');
$posts = Post::all();
```

Comment: Your query was not correctly built. edited my answer

Comment: i tried that and it doesn't work. i think my query was good cuz it did what i wanted when i ran it manualy in phpmyadmin. Also idk do i need to call that function somewhere in the code...

Comment: @Niki a autocommit  with a corelated subquery in SET is allowed, N69S is wrong about that but a LEFT JOIN most likely works more optimal when indexing can be used..  i think lavarel disabled MySQL's autocommit  on the session   try COMMIT after..